# Splitting induvidual WS2812B LEDs

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, computers, rgb, split

My motherboard has a WS2812B header for use in addressable RGB LED strips. However I am not using them for those strips, as instead I would like to use the signal to separately control several other RGB LED devices (fans, reservoir, GPU, monoblock, ...). The WS2812B connector itself is rated at 3A (5V) and needs to be split up into 12V RGB signals (I'm sure 500 mA or so will be fine).

I have some experience with Arduino programming and have the equipment to solder, but any solution that makes it work will be fine. However, it is paramount that there is no way that I can damage my motherboard.

To further clarify, this header on the motherboard has the following pins: +5V, Data and Ground. The motherboard is the ASUS ROG Zenith Extreme. You can find the header I'm talking about on page 40 of [the manual](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/socketTR4/ROG_ZENITH_EXTREME/E13034_ROG_ZENITH_EXTREME_UM_WEB.pdf).

Is this even possible? Is there already some device that makes this work? How would I go about making this work?

Thank you in advance,

CX

Comment: Can you clarify if the WS2812B header as you call it is just a breakout that is intended to be connected to LEDs or LED strips that have the WS2812B chip inbuilt? I imagine it would have at least 3 pins, Power, Ground and DOUT. It would be helpful to know the model of your motherboard so that the technical specifics can be checked.

Comment: If I understand correctly you want a WS2812B to individual RGB pins adaptor.

Comment: @JCollins The former, the motherboard has the 3 pins you're talking about. I updated the post to include this with a link to the manual where I got this information.

Comment: @ratchetfreak Yes that's right. Note that also the voltage needs to be upped for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have "dumb" RGB strips that require 3 PWM signals, you can get WS2811 chips individually [WS2811 @ AliExpress](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Original-100-pcs-WS2811S-2811-WS2811-2811S-chip-LED-SOP-8-driver-chip-integrated-circuit-IC/32687934465.html?spm=2114.search0104.3.2.FyUsHK&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_3_10152_10065_10151_10130_10068_10344_10342_10343_10340_10341_10307_10137_10060_10131_10155_10132_10133_10154_10056_10055_10054_10059_100031_10099_10338_10339_10103_10102_440_10052_10053_10107_10050_10142_10051_10326_10084_10083_10080_10082_10081_10110_10175_10111_10112_10113_10114_143_10312_10313_10314_10078_10079_10073,searchweb201603_19,ppcSwitch_7&btsid=44f24156-1d9a-4d64-a9ad-5e06999709a9&algo_expid=9b85e9e7-7b8a-4a72-9c6f-a451f9b0753f-0&algo_pvid=9b85e9e7-7b8a-4a72-9c6f-a451f9b0753f).

If you get LEDs that have WS2812B chips inbuilt (note: they don't need to be in a strip, they can be individual) then you just route the signal from LED to LED around your case.

Comment: Oh I see, this is perfect! This takes one bit of the signal and forwards it to the next one. This will do just fine! Thank you for the answer. Marking this one as the solution dispite being 17 seconds slower, since you went through the effort of providing a link as well. :)

Comment: Arrgh, I just finished my other comment on the other answer before I saw this... If only there was a thing that popped up to say there had been more activity while you're typing other stuff in the same thread... perhaps there is and I didn't see it. Oh well.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I posted something before I fully understood the protocol and removed it once I got it. Thanks for the explanation anyway, it may still help future people. :)

Answer (score 0):

You will want a WS2811 which is the controller chip embedded into the WS2812b leds. It is available as an IC.

It is meant to drive the LEDs directly using a constant current drive and it can be used to drive 12V LED strips.

Comment: you beat me by 17 seconds...

Comment: Thank you for this solution, it's perfect. I can only mark one answer as solution, but have my upvote instead (which will be visible after I have 15 karma).

Comment: When you say separate RGB signal I'm assuming you mean that you want one LED to be 1 colour, the next to be a different colour etc. This can be done with the WS2811. For each different colour that you want you will need a WS2811. The DOUT of the first WS2811 will go to the DIN of the next and so on, the colour of each of the individual WS2811 is independently controllable. I'm assuming your motherboard has some way on telling it how many LEDs you have connected and what colour you want them to be.

Comment: @JCollins the WS28* protocol has not way of telling the controller how many leds are connected.

Comment: @ratchetfreak That's not what I mean, I'm talking about setting how many LEDs you have connected in possibly some BIOS or other motherboard specific software so that it knows how much data to pump out...

Comment: @JCollins the manual says a max of 60 leds that can be addressed with that.

Comment: @ratchetfreak Yes, that is the maximum, probably based on current limitations, but if you're only going to connect 10 LEDs you're not going to be clocking out data for 60...